# How is Euler fluids equation considered unsolved?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Apart from the Navier-Stokes equation, the Euler equation is described by Clay Math Inst. as unsolved or not well understood. My question is, is there a special case of Euler fluids equation that they are talking about?
P.S: I'm no specialist in this but please I need an answer coherent to someone slightly above a layperson. Thanks

Comment: Which Euler equation is this?

Comment: Did you mean [Euler equations in fluid dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_%28fluid_dynamics%29)?

Comment: Solved by computer fluid modelling numerically. A few years before a claim was made and withdrawn before Clay institute for NSE solution.

Comment: There is somewhat a confusion here but what am asking is the fluid version of Euler equation as described by Clay Math. Is it a special case they are describing or has the issue already been resolved? I still dont get it.